# How can I tell what version of the Invision Power Board forum I am using?

Tags: forum

I have been asked to look after a forum but cannot find out what version it is.

Does anyone know how this can be determined?

http://www.invisionboard.com/

Comment: Doesn't it display the version at the bottom of the screen when viewing your board?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admin Control Panel -> Support tab.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a database table 'ibf_upgrade_history' with a field called 'upgrade version human'. That should do the trick!